# Match opening hours dataframes Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I want to match a dataframe that contains for each day of the week the opening and closing hours with a dataframe that contains a datetime column. The first dataframe I have is:

```
    day_of_week   start  end
0   1             08:00  18:00
1   2             08:00  18:00
2   3             08:00  18:00
3   4             08:00  18:00
4   5             08:00  18:00
5   6             NaN    NaN
6   7             NaN    NaN
```

This dataframe could change, so the method should still work if it changes to, for example, this:

```
    day_of_week   start  end
0   1             08:00  19:00
1   2             08:00  19:00
2   3             08:00  19:00
3   4             08:00  19:00
4   5             08:00  19:00
5   6             08:00  17:00
6   7             NaN    NaN
```

The second dataframe I have is:

```
                            elec    gas  day_of_week
ts          
2022-04-23 00:00:00+02:00   3.6     0.0  5
2022-04-23 01:00:00+02:00   3.6     0.0  5
2022-04-23 02:00:00+02:00   3.2     0.0  5
2022-04-23 03:00:00+02:00   3.2     0.0  5
2022-04-23 04:00:00+02:00   3.2     0.0  5
2022-04-25 09:00:00+02:00   4.0     0.1  1
```

I would like to match the first dataframe with the second as follows:

1. Match 'day_of_week' between the dataframes
2. Determine whether the time in the 'ts' column is between the 'start' and 'end' hours in the first dataframe
3. If it is between those hours and 'start' and 'end' values are not NaN: append column value 'True' to row. Else append column value 'False' to row.

I would like the resulting dataframe to be like this:

```
                            elec    gas  day_of_week DuringHours
ts          
2022-04-23 00:00:00+02:00   3.6     0.0  5           False
2022-04-23 01:00:00+02:00   3.6     0.0  5           False
2022-04-23 02:00:00+02:00   3.2     0.0  5           False
2022-04-23 03:00:00+02:00   3.2     0.0  5           False
2022-04-23 04:00:00+02:00   3.2     0.0  5           False
2022-04-25 09:00:00+02:00   4.0     0.1  1           True
```

How could I achieve that? I have tried the following:

Using between_time:

```
#array = interpolatedUsageDf.index.isin(interpolatedUsageDf.between_time('8:00:00', '18:00:00', include_start=True, include_end=True).index)
```

This did not work perfectly because I want to match it with the other dataframe, which is not possible with between_time

I could use 'np.where' but I don't know how to use that with another dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

If the `start` and `end` hours are the same across all days, then you can simply use:

```
df2['DuringHours'] = np.where((df2['day_of_week'] <= 5) & \
                              (df2.index.hour >= 8) & \
                              (df2.index.hour <= 18) > 0,True,False)
```

Returning:

```
                           elec  gas  day_of_week  DuringHours
ts                                                            
2022-11-14 00:00:00+02:00   3.6  0.0            5        False
2022-11-14 01:00:00+02:00   3.6  0.0            5        False
2022-11-14 02:00:00+02:00   3.2  0.0            5        False
2022-11-14 03:00:00+02:00   3.2  0.0            5        False
2022-11-14 04:00:00+02:00   3.2  0.0            5        False
2022-11-14 09:00:00+02:00   4.0  0.1            1         True
```

Comment: This could work in theory, but I really need to match it to the other dataframe because that dataframe could change.